# How to match array of values to another array of traits?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, matching

I need to divide a list of unique traits (for example `["Top","Middle","Bottom"], three of five traits`) between sets of different percentages that describe the traits, looking like this:

```
[
  [
    4.545454545454546,
    4.545454545454546,
    27.27272727272727,
    27.27272727272727,
    36.36363636363637
  ],
  [
    13.043478260869565,
    8.695652173913043,
    26.08695652173913,
    34.78260869565217,
    17.391304347826086
  ],
  [
    33.33333333333333,
    16.666666666666664,
    33.33333333333333,
    0,
    16.666666666666664
  ]
]
```

where each index of such a set

```
[
    33.33333333333333,
    16.666666666666664,
    33.33333333333333,
    0,
    16.666666666666664
]
```

describes the percentage for one of the five traits.

Now I can't just compare for each trait the values with e.g. an `Math.max()`, cause if there are the same percentages (which is in fact very likely), it can't select randomly, but has to compare the remaining traits, to match the traits to the percentages accordingly.
And I just can't think of a way to have this remaining trait comparison.

Edit: An expected output would be, given the traits `["Top","Middle","Bottom"]` corresponding to the first three values and the values of the above example `[2,1,0]`. Where in this array the index matches the trait index and the value the index of the value set. In this case set 3, index 2, would get the trait `top`, as it has the highest top-value and no other set has a high top value, set 2 the `middle` value, as its `bottom` value is lower than the first sets value, and the first set would be bottom, as it has the highest `bottom` value compared to the other values.

Edit 2:
Expected input:

Traits that should be compared: `["Top","Middle","Bottom"]`

Input sets of values:

```
[
  [
    4.545454545454546,
    4.545454545454546,
    27.27272727272727,
    27.27272727272727, // given but not needed, as only the first three traits a relevant in this case
    36.36363636363637 // given but not needed
  ],
  [
    13.043478260869565,
    8.695652173913043,
    26.08695652173913,
    34.78260869565217, // given but not needed
    17.391304347826086 // given but not needed
  ],
  [
    33.33333333333333,
    16.666666666666664,
    33.33333333333333,
    0, // given but not needed
    16.666666666666664 // given but not needed
  ]
]
```

Expected output:

Distribution of traits across value sets: `[2,1,0]` (corresponding to `["Top","Middle","Bottom"]`)

Comment: Can you show expected output?

Comment: Are you looking for a weighted random selection?

Comment: You have 5 percentages but only 3 traits. How do they map to each other?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski just edited the post to include the expected output.

Comment: @Barmar That actually sounds like what I want, besides the randomness. I probable should look more into a weighted selection. thx
(and the three values in this case correspond to the first three values in the sets. There actually are 5 traits in this case, thus five values, but I only mentioned three as an example, mb)

Comment: I can't understand your expected output. Don't describe it, show it as an actual array of inputs and results.